# How to style a Dropdown menu with React & bootstrap to be 100% width

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm creating a navbar for a website using React and Bootstrap.

Some of the navbar links will open a dropdown menu, which I want to be the full width of the page, but it currently only opens to be the width of the navbar link.

What am I missing in my code?

**The navbar code** (with conditional rendering based on whether the button will trigger the dropdown)

```
 <div className={`${styles.tempNavBottom} container-fluid`}>
      {navData && navData.mainMenu.map((item:any, i:number) => {
        if (item.dropdown){
        // objects with 'dropdown' property will trigger a dropdown to appear
          return dropdownButtons(item, i)
        } else {
          return <Link className="text-decoration-none my-auto" href={item.url} key={i}>{item.title}</Link>
        }
      })}
    </div>
```

**The dropdown code**

```
const dropdownButtons = (item: any, i: number) => {
   return (
     <li
       className="tf-grey text-decoration-none my-auto dropdown list-unstyled"
       key={i}
     >
       <a
         role="button"
         className="btn dropdown-toggle"
         type="button"
         data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
         data-bs-display="static"
         aria-haspopup="true"
         aria-expanded="false"
         id={`${item.title}-dropdown`}
       >
         {item.title}
       </a>
       <div
         className="dropdown-menu p-3 w-100 open"
         role="menu"
         aria-labelledby={`${item.title}-dropdown`}
       >
         <a className="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
         <a className="dropdown-item">Item 2</a>
       </div>
     </li>
   );
 };
```

**CSS for .tempNavBottom class**

```
.tempNavBottom {
  height:50px;
  width:100vw;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: rgb(61, 60, 60);
  position:absolute;
  transform: translateY(65px);
  z-index:10;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Edit:

I've tried recreating the navbar here: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-cloud-v822qy?file=/src/App.js)

Although for some reason the dropdown doesn't function correctly on codesandbox... Annoyingly!

Comment: The reference point for absolute positioning is the nearest [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block) - most often in scenarios like this, an ancestor that has `position: relative` set - probably the parent `li` here.

Comment: Although with the `width:100vw;` you set, it should at least be this wide, even if it doesn't start from the desired left offset point - so if that is not the case, then there is probably cut-off `overflow` involved somewhere as well. In short: You have not shown us enough code to see the full picture. You are supposed to present a proper [mre] of your issue, when asking questions like this here.

Comment: And please tag appropriately - you are most likely not using `bootstrap-4` and `bootstrap-5` at the same time, I am guessing - so please tag only the appropriate version, and not irrelevant stuff, thanks.

Comment: Hi @CBroe and thanks for the comments. What more do you need to produce a minimal reproducible example? The JSX elements of what I'm trying to replicate are there. I'm trying to learn.

Do you have any suggestions of what to use instead of ```position: relative``` for the parent ```li```?
Thank you

Comment: _"The JSX elements of what I'm trying to replicate are there"_ - yeah, fine - but I do not have a whole development setup for a react application just floating around here on my end. It would really be preferable, if you could present what is basically a HTML and CSS problem, by showing us the rendered HTML plus the CSS, as a minimal working example of the issue (and then you "translate" whatever the solution will be, back into your react setting yourself.)

Comment: Some online react playgrounds also exist, so you could show it via one of those as well. But, as said, this is basically a pure HTML & CSS issue - so why even raise the bar for anyone who might be willing to help and has the expertise in HTML & CSS to do so, any higher, by presenting code specific to one particular framework.

Comment: @CBroe I've recreated a small part of it here, although annoyingly the dropdown element isn't working despite the code being identical in my code editor.... Sorry

[link] (https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-cloud-v822qy?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: `position: static` for the `li` should probably already get you most of the way there.